# Facebook Ads Attribution Data - Error #100

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Pretty straightforward: I'm trying to get Facebook ads attribution data for my Android app using Open Graph API (so I can detect which users came from Facebook ads, which ad, etc). When I use the below url, I get the following error:

> {    "error": {
>         "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (activities) on node type (Application)",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 100,
>         "fbtrace_id": "H4b8LYlSGeN"    } }

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{app_id}/activities?access_token={token}&event=MOBILE_APP_INSTALL&attribution={attribution_id}
```

I got the method via [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api) in their documentation, which does appear to indicate it works the way I expect.

Am I missing something here? Am I using a totally wrong method to get attribution data?

Comment: I assume “using the URL” means you made a GET request …? Needs to be a POST …

Comment: Yep I'm dumb, that's it *facepalm*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a GET request rather than a POST because I'm a dumdum